# Return value from Async Task class for reverse geocoding purpose

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-maps-api-2

I'm using the reverse geocoding from the GMaps API V2. I included in my activity an Async Task class that do the reverse geocoding and is able to modify a textView.

However, I'd like to be able when I click on a Button (defined in the onCreate method of my activity) to upload the address I got from the Async Task on my Parse backend.

How do I access to the address variable outside the Async Task but in my activity ?

Thank you,

Arnaud

Comment: Coul you post some code please ?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't if it is a local to the `doInBackground()` method. The way to do it would be to wrap the interesting objects in a class and return an instance of that class. Then your post execute callback can use the objects as needed.

Comment: Sorry, Arnaud, I don't understand your question.